# oracle self outer join filtering records

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

```
SELECT A.EMP_ID A_EMP_ID,
  A.EMP_CODE A_EMP_CODE,
  B.EMP_ID B_EMP_ID,
  B.EMP_CODE B_EMP_CODE,
  C.EMP_ID C_EMP_ID,
  C.EMP_CODE C_EMP_CODE,
FROM EMP A
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP B
ON A.U_CODE =B.U_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP C
ON A.U_CODE =C.U_CODE
WHERE A.SRC ='A'
AND B.SRC  ='B'
AND C.SRC  ='C'
```

For one employee I have data from different sources and where his id is different all systems. There are more than 5 different source system from where data is coming to this table.
u_code will remain same in all the sources. Emp is having each row from each system.

Now, I need to build a cross walk table where in one row I can give all the source system id for single employee. Above query is working fine if employee is having data in all three systems but is filtering out data if its present only in two systems.

Table data

```
empid,emp_code,src,u_code
1,ABC,A,101
2,PQR,B,101
3,XYZ,C,101
4,KPO,A,102
5,LIP,B,102
```

Query should return

```
A_EMP_ID,A_EMP_CODE,B_EMP_ID,B_EMP_CODE,C_EMP_ID,C_EMP_CODE
1,ABC,2,PQR,3,XYZ,101
4,KPO,5,LIP,,,102
```

Query is working fine for 101 u_code but not returing 102

Database is Oracle 10g

Comment: Just for other user, I have use oracle pivot function for this requirement. Made job much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an outer join, you need to be careful about conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM EMP A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     EMP B
     ON A.U_CODE = B.U_CODE AND B.SRC = 'B' LEFT OUTER JOIN
     EMP C
    ON A.U_CODE = C.U_CODE AND C.SRC  = 'C'
WHERE A.SRC = 'A'
```

What is happening in your version is that non-matching rows in `B` and `C` are generated filled with `NULL` values.  `NULL` values obviously fail the `WHERE` conditions, so these rows are filtered out.  The effect is the same as doing an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks its working fine. But now its returning record if its present for A source. If record is present is not there A then its not returning for B and C source

Comment: As my initial problem was handled by your suggesting hence selected your problem. I have gone for pivot for this functionality

Answer (score 1):

When you can't guarantee that any specific value for SRC is precent for any value of U_CODE, one possible solution is to start with an instance of EMP without any filtering, and then do `LEFT JOIN` once for each possible value of SRC, checking the values of SRC in the join conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       A.EMP_ID, A.EMP_CODE,
       B.EMP_ID, B.EMP_CODE,
       C.EMP_ID, C_EMP_CODE
FROM EMP U
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP A ON A.U_CODE = U.U_CODE AND A.SRC = 'A'
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP B ON B.U_CODE = U.U_CODE AND B.SRC = 'B'
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP C ON C.U_CODE = U.U_CODE AND C.SRC = 'C'
```

Comment: Thanks. Its giving desired result. However, I have went for pivot function. Up voting your answer